# Numbers input in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know this should be an easy thing but I don't know how to do it.

I want to insert some data into a table, and I'm using loops because I have over 1million datas to insert. It should look like this `"PM-0000000000, PM-0000000001......... PM-0000099999"`. Now here's the problem. I don't know how to add those zeros in front according to the numbers that are after the zeros. the number length (`PM-"0000000000"`) Should always be 10.

Help please ?

Comment: Look at String.Format(), e.g. `string str = string.Format("{0:d6}", number);`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use padleft to fill the string with the number of zeros you need

```
string value="99999";
string concat= "PM" + value.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString

```
int yourNumber = 999;
string filledNumber = yourNumber.ToString("D10");
```

Where `D10` means, your number will be filled to 10 digits.

Comment: This is my preference, since it's easier to see how many digits it's supposed to have.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `string result = number.ToString("0000000000");`

But I prefer @Kasyx's answer above. (I added this answer for completeness.)

Answer (score 2):

you can generate full code using `string.Format`

```
string.Format("PM-{0:D10}", intval)
```